# Experimental Design Chlamydomonas

Tags: r, linear-regression, lme4, anova

I am trying to fit a model but I am confused about what I am doing wrong as my summary model says its boundary is singular.
So my study is to investigate the effect of temperature on the growth rate of a model algal species, Chlamydomonas reinhardtii. Five temperatures (10 ◦C, 15 ◦C, 20 ◦C, 25 ◦C, 30 ◦C) were set up for
cultivating the algae. To maintain exponential growth, the algal cells were cultured under
sufficient light and nutrient conditions. To investigate whether different strains of the same species grow differently, ten strains were randomly selected from a larger species pool. Four replicates were set up for each strain under each temperature.

So I fitted a mixed model where the temperature is fixed and strain is random. This is the code I used.
Z.lmer<-lmer(Growth~Temperature+(1|StrainID/Temperature), data=MyData)
I am getting this

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: log10Growth ~ Temperature + (1 | StrainID/Temperature)
   Data: MyData

REML criterion at convergence: -175.3

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.9327 -0.6274  0.1274  0.6713  2.1528 

Random effects:
 Groups               Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Temperature:StrainID (Intercept) 0.00000  0.0000  
 StrainID             (Intercept) 0.12350  0.3514  
 Residual                         0.01683  0.1297  
Number of obs: 199, groups:  Temperature:StrainID, 50; StrainID, 10

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   0.63110    0.11151   5.660
Temperature1 -0.17246    0.01836  -9.394
Temperature2 -0.04106    0.01836  -2.236
Temperature3  0.01812    0.01836   0.987
Temperature4  0.13341    0.01854   7.195

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Tmprt1 Tmprt2 Tmprt3
Temperatur1  0.000                     
Temperatur2  0.000 -0.248              
Temperatur3  0.000 -0.248 -0.248       
Temperatur4  0.001 -0.253 -0.253 -0.253
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

here its boundary is singular which means I can't go on with this model,right?
Can anyone help how to proceed with this?

Comment: Is there a reason you selected temperature as a factor variable and not as a continuous variable?

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake here.. `Z.lmer<- lmer( log10Growth~ Temperature*StrainID+(1|StrainID/ExptID), data=MyData)` I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

The interaction variance is 0. Probably better to reduce your model in the random part to :

```
(1 | StrainID)
```

You may run two models m1 and m2, one with and other without interaction as I indicated above and compare the two moedls e.g, with :

```
anova(m1,m2)
```

and choose the best model based on criteria (AIC, BIC, loglik). Hope it helps.